# jquery tooltip / moves with mouse move / tooltip with mouse position

Tags: jquery, plugins, tooltip

The [jQuery Tools tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) is ok for me!

But i want it to move with mouse move (tooltip relative to mouse position). How can i do that? Or is there any other plugin in this way?

Comment: IMO, you should accept nullability's answer.  The native jQuery tooltip has seen a lot of progress since this question was originally answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do with the jQuery TOOLS tooltip plugin.

The [Bassistance Tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) does support what you want. Use `track: true`, as in [this demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/#yahoo):

```
$('#yahoo a').tooltip({ 
    track: true, 
    delay: 0, 
    showURL: false, 
    showBody: " - ", 
    fade: 250 
});
```

---

If you don't like that plugin, [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) also supports mouse tracking. See [this demo](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#mouse) (equivalent jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/v6KMr/)).

```
$('#demo-mouse').qtip({
    content: 'I position myself at the current mouse position',
    position: {
        my: 'top left',
        target: 'mouse',
        viewport: $(window), // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
        adjust: {
            x: 10,  y: 10
        }
    },
    hide: {
        fixed: true // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
    },
    style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
});
```

Comment: See below for the most upvoted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15163105/4047679

Answer (score 19):

jQuery UI now includes a `.tooltip()` widget as of version 1.9, and it now provides the option `track: true` to make tooltips follow the mouse. Just specify it as an option when initializing the widget:

```
$( document ).tooltip({
    track: true
});
```

See this in action here: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#tracking

This is useful if you are already using jQuery UI and do not want to include another library. Check out the API for more details about this widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: This should be the selected answer now.  The native tooltip has seen a lot of progress since this question was originally answered.

Answer (score 2):

I do this with jQuery Tools tooltip

```
$('#selector').mousemove(function(e) { 
  $('.tooltip').css('left', e.pageX + 5).css('top', e.pageY - 25).css('display', 'block');
})
```

where .tooltip is the css class

Answer (score 0):

***HTML***

```
<div id="tooltipWindow" class="tooltipContainer">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

***CSS*** (Add styles as you want, in the script below I have also added the attached element's class to the tooltip div)

```
<style>
    .tooltipContainer {
        position: fixed;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background: ghostwhite;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (jQuery, dont forget to include the jQuery library, I have added the include tag as well)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    //Following Tooltip
    $('.elementClassName').mousemove(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('title') != "") {
            $('#tooltipWindow div').html($(this).attr('title'));
            $('#tooltipWindow').css('left', e.clientX + 10).css('top', e.clientY + 10).addClass($(this).attr('class'));
            $('#tooltipWindow').show();
        }
    });
    $('.elementClassName').mouseleave(function (e) {
        $('#tooltipWindow').hide();
        });
    }

    //Non Following Tooltip
    $('.elementClassName').hover(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('title') != "") {
            $('#tooltipWindow div').html($(this).attr('title'));
            $('#tooltipWindow').css('left', e.clientX + 10).css('top', e.clientY + 10).addClass($(this).attr('class'));
            $('#tooltipWindow').show();
        }
    },function (e) {
        $('#tooltipWindow').hide();
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
   window.onmousemove = function (e) {
     var tooltips = $('div.ui-tooltip');
     var x = (e.clientX + 10) + 'px',
        y = (e.clientY + 10) + 'px';
     for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
       tooltips[i].style.top = y;
       tooltips[i].style.left = x;
    }
  };
});
```

If you use jquery-ui tooltip, that code fragment will do the trick!