# Tooltip over different cells of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display tooltip on different cells of table.

Basically what I want is a new layer of tool tip over that cell. It is necessary the cell can be anywhere.

I have seen some jQuery library that apply tooltip to last column of table which won't work for me, so tooltip should appear anywhere in the middle of table or at the end.

Anyone can please suggest me any jQuery library I could use? Or any JavaScript way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya is this what you are looking for **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/UXR8u/

Although there is a tooltip plugin you can also look at. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip  **link** might help: (contains demo for tooltip and qtip) [jquery tooltip / moves with mouse move / tooltip with mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795078/jquery-tooltip-moves-with-mouse-move-tooltip-with-mouse-position)

**jquery code**

```
$(function () {
    $(".test").hover(
        function () {
            var toolTipHtml = $("#ToolTipDIv").clone();
            $(this).append(toolTipHtml);
            toolTipHtml.show("slow");
        },
        function () {
            var toolTipHtml = $(this).find(".tooltip");
            toolTipHtml.hide();
            toolTipHtml.remove();
        }
    );
});

​
```

Comment: Thanks this will work I think. I will accept your answer in an hour.

Answer (score 1):

you can use qTip2 plugin:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/